# Is a complex number $\lambda$ in the resolvent set $\rho(T)$ of $T$?

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectra

Let $\lambda \notin \{0_{\mathbb C}\} \cup \sigma_p(T)$. Show that $\lambda$ is in the resolvent set $\rho(T)$ of $T \in \mathcal L(\ell^2(\mathbb C))$, where
$$
T(x_n) = \left(\frac{x_n}{n}\right)\,.
$$

The point spectrum $\sigma_p(T)$ was defined as
\begin{equation}
\sigma_p(T) = \{ \lambda \in \mathbb C \mid (\lambda I - T) \text{ is not injective} \}
\end{equation}
and the resolvent set $\rho(T)$ as
\begin{equation}
\rho(T) = \{ \lambda \in \mathbb C \mid (\lambda I - T)^{-1} \in \mathcal L(\ell^2(\mathbb C)) \}\,.
\end{equation}

#### An attempt

By definition, for $\lambda$ to be in the resolvent set $\rho(T)$, the relation
$$
\Vert(\lambda I - T)^{-1}x\Vert_2 \leq  M\Vert x \Vert_2
$$
should hold for all $x \in \ell^2(\mathbb C)$ and some $M > 0$. By assumption, we know that for the $\lambda$ in question, $(\lambda I - T)$ is injective, so for any two distinct $x, y \in \ell^2(\mathbb C)$ we have
$$
(\lambda I - T)x \neq (\lambda I - T) y \,.
$$
By writing $x = (\lambda I - T) y$ for a suitable $y \in \ell^2(\mathbb C)$, the $2$-norm of our inverse image becomes
$$
\Vert(\lambda I - T)^{-1} x\Vert_2
= \Vert(\lambda I - T)^{-1} (\lambda I - T) y\Vert_2
= \Vert y\Vert_2
\leq M \Vert y\Vert_2
$$
for $M = 1$.

Is this sufficient or am I missing something crucial, especially conceptually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda\neq 0$ such that $(T-\lambda I)$ is injective and define $S:=(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$
Note that $S$ is given by $(Sy)_{n}=\frac{y_n}{\frac{1}{n}-\lambda}.$

Since $\lambda\not\in \{0\}\cup \{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}},$ we get that $$
d:=\inf_{n\in \mathbb{N}} |\frac{1}{n}-\lambda|>0
$$
and thus, $|(Sy)_n|\leq \frac{|y_n|}{d},$ which implies that $\| S(y)\|_{\ell^2}\leq \frac{\|y\|_{\ell^2}}{d} $. We conclude that $S$ is bounded and $\lambda \in \rho(T)$.

Comment: So the big thing here is that I need to actually specify a concrete sequence with the help of $S \coloneqq (T - \lambda I)^{-1}$, as we know what $T$ ''looks like'', so we can actually find out what $S$ is?

Comment: This exercise is particular to the setup where $T$ is a multiplication operator, yes. I'm not sure what you mean by specifying a concrete sequence, though.

Comment: I guess I'm again mixing up what is supposed to be in $\mathbb C$ and what in $\ell^2(\mathbb C)$. Since the multiplicaton operator $T$ is well defined, it has a well defined inverse, so we don't need to deal with arbitrary $T \in \mathcal L(\ell^2(\mathbb C))$.

Comment: Well, the statement is not true for $T\in \mathcal{L}(\ell^2(\mathbb{C})$. There are operators with no eigenvalues but spectrum equal to all of $[0,1]$.

Comment: I guess one more point of confusion is, that is $\sigma_p(T) = \{1/n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$ really? Couldn't there be other eigenvalues in the point spectrum $\sigma_p(T)$?

Comment: This is a matter of solving the linear equation $Tx=\lambda x$. I trust you can do this yourself. Also... if you read the above proof I didn't actually at any point claim that there weren't other eigenvalues. As a completely roundabout way of proving the statement, though, it also follows from the above that there aren't any other eigenvalues.

Comment: Right, I actually did that already. So the confusion was basically about me not getting the fact that solutions to the eigenvalue equation are the members of the point spectrum.

Comment: If $T-\lambda I$ is not injective, then its kernel is nontrivial.

Comment: Right, so non-injectivity is the generalized version of determinant-is-zero-condition for finding out the eigenvalues of matrices.

Comment: That's sort of backwards. The spectrum of a matrix is also just defined as the $\lambda$ such that $(T-\lambda I)$ is not invertible. A way of checking this is calculating the determinant, but there is nothing new about the general spectrum definition.